# Can the ratio of chord to radius be constant if the chord divides the semi-circle equally?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area

Suppose there is a semi-circle. It has a chord parallel to the diameter which divides the area into two parts of equal area.

- Would the angle made by the chord at the center be constant?
- Would the ratio of radius and chord be constant? If yes, what would be the value?

One of the approach to solve the second problem would be like following:

Let the radius be $R$ and the length of chord be $C$. Area of circular segment(⌓) would be $\pi R^2/4$. Another way to calculate the area of circular segment would be to calculate the area of circular sector(⌔)  first and then subtract the area of the triangle formed by two radius and chord. Hence,

> $\pi R^2/4 = R^2\theta/2 - R^2\sin\theta/2$
> $\theta = 2\sin^{-1}\frac{C}{2R}$

where  $\theta$ is the angle made by the chord at the center.

The hunch says $\theta$ must be constant. But someone is stuck as he doesn't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: After you cancel out a factor of $R^2$ the first equation is an equation in $\theta$ alone which does not depend on $R$. Solve it for $\theta$ then the second equation shows that $C/R$ is also constant. Which also follows by similarity.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B%5Cpi%2C2%5D+%3D+%5Ctheta+-+sin%5Ctheta $\theta=2.30988$ and $C/R = 1.82954$

Answer (score 2):

As OP has computed,
$$ \pi R^2/4 = R^2\theta/2 - R^2\sin\theta/2.$$

Hence, $\pi /4 = \theta/2 - \sin\theta/2$.

Let $f(x)=x/2 - \sin x/2$.

- $f(0)=0$.
- $f(\pi)= \pi/2$.
- $f'(x)=(1-\cos x)/2 > 0$ if $0\lt \theta\lt\pi$.

Hence, $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function on $[0, \pi]$ with
$f(0)<\pi/4<f(\pi)$. That means, there is unique solution to the equation $f(x)=\pi/4$ for $0\le x\le\pi$.

Since $\theta$ is a solution, $x=\theta$ must be that unique solution.  That means $\theta$ is a constant. Hence, $C/R=2\sin(\theta/2)$ is also a constant.

Comment: There is no "closed formula" for $\theta$ or $C/R$. So, we can be content to find an approximate value. For example, OP found $\theta\approx2.30988$ using Wolfram.